Two functors having the same right adjoint functor.
Let $F,G:C\to D$ be two functors. Suppose that $F$ and $G$ have the same right adjoint functor, does this imply that $F=G$?
I know that $F^*=G^*$  implies that for all $c\in C$ and all $d\in D$ we have a natural bijection
$$Hom_C(F(c), d)\cong Hom_D(G(c),d)$$
but does this imply that $F=G$?

It doesn't imply that they are equal, but are isomorphic, i.e. there is a natural isomorphism between $F$ and $G$, due to Yoneda embedding.

Yoneda says that  if for all $c\in C$ and all $d\in D$ we have a natural bijection
$$Hom_C(F(c), d)\cong Hom_D(G(c),d)$$
then $F$ is isomorphsic to $G$ ?
